# Did princess Maria von Hohenzollern-Sigmaringen -Belgian king Albert's mother- have a child out of wedlock?

Tags: nobility

Maria Luise von Hohenzollern-Sigmaringen in German. She was married to prince Philip of Belgium and was the mother of king Albert I.

Just one source and no other more -[Wikipedia in Spanish](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mar%C3%ADa_de_Hohenzollern-Sigmaringen) - claims that she, in her youth, had a child out of wedlock, whose father was Pierre Antoine Lacouture d'Orleans, prince d'Orleans.

This gentleman and all the others mentioned in the article can not be found anywhere at all on the Internet.These personages are: her purported son, Louise Anton de Lacouture de Hohenzollern-Sigmaringen y de Orleans; his wife, Marie Rockefeller Spelman, an alleged John Rockefeller's daughter, and her present-day descendant Pierre Lacouture Rockefeller de Hohenzollern-Sigmaringen y Murat, 9th prince of Murat. Some of their names and titles are in Spanish, the language used in the article. No other language-version of Wikipedia deals with this topic.

Chances are the article is a hoax. Please do not advise me to get in touch with Wikipedia.

The question is simple. No ambiguity, no vagueness.

I couldn't add the link, but it works.
In any case it is:https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mar%C3%ADa_de_Hohenzollern-Sigmaringen

[enter link description here](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mar%C3%ADa_de_Hohenzollern-Sigmaringen)

Comment: Is there a citation on Spanish Wikipedia to support the assertion?

Answer (score 6):

It seems highly unlikely that this story is true.

Searches on other sites (not just Wikipedia) do not mention it at all.  There is no citation on the Spanish Wikipedia page to support the claim.

---

It is always worth checking the edit history in these cases.

The page was [edited](https://es.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Mar%C3%ADa_de_Hohenzollern-Sigmaringen&diff=prev&oldid=109119066) to include the claim by an anonymous editor on 6 July 2018.  No supporting citations were included in support of the claim.

If we look at the contributions by that [anonymous editor](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Especial:Contribuciones/181.138.182.64), we see that this is the only page that they have contributed to.

---

Given the lack of any supporting citation, and the fact that a search of other sites has failed to find any evidence whatsoever to support the claim, I would treat it as spurious.

---

This is just an example of what can happen with a crowdsourced resource like Wikipedia, and why one should always be cautious about taking claims without a supporting citation at face value.

Answer (score 6):

*To add to sempaiscuba's answer:*

Although there was a 'Prince Pierre d'Orleans', his full name was [Pierre Philippe Jean Marie d'Orléans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre,_Duke_of_Penthi%C3%A8vre), not *Pierre Antoine Lacouture d'Orleans.* The only other 'Prince Pierre' is [13th generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princes_of_Orl%C3%A9ans) and would appear to be still living (and is maybe still a child).

The supposed son *Louise Anton de Lacouture de Hohenzollern-Sigmaringen y de Orleans*' supposed wife does not exist: according to the [Rockefeller Archive Center](https://rockarch.org/bio/famtree.php), John D. Rockfeller did not have a daughter called Marie (or Maria or Mary etc).

The Spanish Wikipedia page for [John D. Rockefeller](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_D._Rockefeller) was edited to add 'Marie' at around about the same time as *Maria Luise von Hohenzollern-Sigmaringen*'s Spanish page was edited. However, 'Marie' does not appear on the English, Portuguese or French (or any other) pages I checked for JDR.

The alleged present-day descendant *Pierre Lacouture Rockefeller de Hohenzollern-Sigmaringen y Murat* cannot be the [9th prince of Murat](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mar%C3%ADa_de_Hohenzollern-Sigmaringen). The current prince is [Joachim; he's the 8th prince](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joachim,_8th_Prince_Murat) and is very much alive. His current heir is also called [Joachim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joachim,_Prince_of_Pontecorvo) and will presumably become the 9th prince when papa departs.